# Values are missing when using df.loc after changing the index in python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Changed the Index to 'PassengerId', then tried the `df.loc` function to retrieve info based on the new Index but the result contains missing values

Was exploring the Titanic dataset.

> 1. Appended a new_row with some values.
> 2. Changed Index to PassengerId.
> 3. Tried searching using df.loc.
> 4. Got result with values vanishing in the existing rows, but displaying value of the new appended row.

```
# Loading the dataset in to a Data Frame
dataset= pd.read_csv('Titanic_train.csv')
# Add a New Row at the bottom to the Dataset 
new_row=pd.Series(data=['892','0','1','NA','NA','NA'], index=['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age'])
dataset=dataset.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
# Setting PassengerId as Index
dataset= dataset.set_index(dataset['PassengerId'])
dataset.loc[['892','891','890']]
```

Getting the Below Result:

```
NaN for all the rows except for the new_row(892)



FutureWarning: Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative`

See the documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike
```

```
 PassengerId PassengerId Survived Pclass Name Sex Age SibSp Parch Ticket Fare Cabin Embarked                                                
 892 892 0 1 NA NA NA NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 891 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 890 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
    PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age SibSp   Parch   Ticket  Fare    Cabin   Embarked
PassengerId                                             
890 890 1   1   Behr, Mr. Karl Howell male 26   0.0 0.0 111369  30.00 C148 C
891 891 0   3   Dooley, Mr. Patrick male 32 0.0 0.0 370376  7.75    NaN Q
892 892 0   1   NA  NA  NA  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the new_row I mentioned values of int type columns like "PassengerId' , 'Age' etc as '892' instead of only 892.  That had changed the type to object from int for most of the columns. Removing the inverted comma solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

Running a test ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset= pd.DataFrame(columns=["PassengerId","Survived","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"],data=[[891,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],[892,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]])
print(dataset)
# Add rows
new_row=pd.Series(data=['890','0','1','NA','NA','NA'], index=['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age'])
dataset=dataset.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

# Setting PassengerId as Index
dataset= dataset.set_index(dataset['PassengerId'])
dataset.loc[[892,891,890]]
print(dataset)
```

And yielding the following result:

```
  PassengerId  Survived  Pclass  Name  Sex  Age  SibSp  Parch  Ticket  Fare  \
0          891         1     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   
1          892         2     NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   

   Cabin  Embarked  
0    NaN       NaN  
1    NaN       NaN  
            PassengerId Survived Pclass Name  Sex  Age  SibSp  Parch  Ticket  \
PassengerId                                                                    
891                 891        1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   
892                 892        2    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN   
890                 890        0      1   NA   NA   NA    NaN    NaN     NaN   

             Fare  Cabin  Embarked  
PassengerId                         
891           NaN    NaN       NaN  
892           NaN    NaN       NaN  
890           NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Seems to be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: But all the values in 891 and 892 have vanished. I am expecting a result which has existing values.

Comment: Dummy data in my dataset. I have only inserted values into "Survived" column.  Nevertheless, still trying to replicate your issue ...

Comment: thank you @Kryesec, I just figured out the error I made. It solved the issue.

Comment: When adding the new_row I mentioned values of int type columns like "PassengerId' , 'Age' etc as '892' instead of only 892.  That had changed the type to object from int for most of the columns. Removing the inverted comma solved the issue.\

Comment: np! datatypes could mess up anyone's day ._____.